# Comparing JSON Response with String in Python

Tags: python, json

I am currently developing a filter for JSON responses. I am basically just confused as to why Truth_Value in this code is printing as False.

```
import urllib
import json
from urllib2 import urlopen

entry="pocket"
url="http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track.json?q="
user_query=urllib.quote_plus(entry)
url +=user_query
response = urlopen(url)
json_obj = json.load(response)

print json.dumps(json_obj['tracks'][3]['name'])
# This prints to "In Your Pocket"

Truth_Value=json.dumps(json_obj['tracks'][3]['name'])=="In Your Pocket"
print Truth_Value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, `json.dumps(json_obj['tracks'][3]['name'])` returns `"In Your Pocket"`... but with the quotes, while you are comparing it with the string without quotes.

I just did a simple test:

```
print "// " + json.dumps(json_obj['tracks'][3]['name']) + " //"
print "// In Your Pocket //"
```

This will print:

```
// "In Your Pocket" //
// In Your Pocket //
```

So if you want `Truth_value` to be `True`, you should do

```
Truth_Value=json.dumps(json_obj['tracks'][3]['name'])=="\"In Your Pocket\""
```

Comment: Thank you, I actually just saw the difference a minute ago

Comment: I'm glad you found it! :)

Comment: @courtorder52 don't hesitate to upvote and/or accept answers that helped you out

Comment: @TimCastelijns tried to, but i'm new to stack overflow and don't have high enough of a reputation to upvote yet.